# Repeat php script after time out

Tags: php

My php script creates thumbnails of images. Sometimes when it handles a lot of images, the script have to run a long time and ends after 60 seconds because of the time limit on my server.

Can I tell the script to time out after 59sek and then repeat itself?

I need some ideas.

Edit:
I don't think my web hosting allows me to change max_execution_time

Comment: I take it you can't change the server's time limit?

Answer (score 2):

I can't believe this is my answer..

loopMe.php:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="65;url=loopMe.php">
<?php

  /* code that is timing out here */

?>
```

Your best bet though may be to look at `set_time_limit()` like others have suggested.

Important Note: this loop will never end.  You could however have a session variable, say, `$_SESSION['stopLoop']` to flag whenever the script successfully ends.  Before printing the meta-refresh line you can check the value of that.

Comment: +1 the most workable answer right now and worth serious consideration: A purely PHP-driven solution would be much harder to implement!

Comment: +1 for setting a flag when the script has actually finished. You can then obviously show your success message and whatever else.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modify your code, use the set_time_limit(0), which sets to have no time limit.

```
set_time_limit(0)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

I wouldn't recommend to use though, if your system grows this would take a very long time processing. It is better to recode in such a way that you run that only when your server is on low traffic and control how much time it will process data.

For instance you could store the data you need to process in a queue and process as much as you can in a time widow once per night.

Answer (score 0):

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah as above suggested use `set_time_limit` It will increase the sript execution timeout.

If your are in loop for processing multiple files then do `set_time_limit` every time you before you process the file to the expected duration of time. i.e if a file is assumed to take max **60s** for execution before processing use `set_time_limit(60)`

Answer (score 0):

If your server is not runnig with php in [safe mode](http://www.php.net/manual/es/ini.sect.safe-mode.php#ini.safe-mode) you can use set_time_limit($time); where $time is the time you need to execute the script, for example you can use set_time_limit(240); set the timeout on 4 minutes.

Or for example you can find out in your script how much time has passed and before the timeout expires add some seconds (set_time_limit(10);) until the script finish. (if you call multiple times to set_time_limit() you will add the time of each call.)

Using [this](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/elapsed-time.html) code you can calculate the elapsed time and after for each image you compare it against the server timeout.

Also you can modify your script to log the images that has been already processed and in case of timeout carry on with the task in teh same point.

You can run your script from a cron job in your server (if it's allow you) to make it run periodically. Take a look at this [article](http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/running-php-scripts-with-cron/)